# Can b be equal to 15?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If  the equation
$$x^8 – 3abx + a^2 = 0$$
has one root that is $\ge 3$.
And if $a\geq 0$ .

Can $b$ be equal to 15?

**I took One root of this equation is (3 + t), where t ≥ 0
And put the value of this root in equation.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $a$ is what?...

Comment: @Daniel it is not given .It is positive.

Comment: Think of it as a quadratic in $a$.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott Actually it is a multiple choice question. I know the answer is cannot be equal to 15.Thats why i have made up my question according to that.There are 4 more options.

Comment: Does x belong to the set of real numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Try to solve for $a$ in terms of $x$ when $b=15$

Your solution should include a square root.  Can you spot anything about this square root when $x \ge 3$?